# How to copy word and excel files and keep the links between them (charts from excel in word)

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, links

I have these files:
-Word 1
-Excel 1
In Word 1 there are charts which I manually copied (linked) from Excel 1.

I want to copy those files and keep the links between the charts, obviously the data in Excel 2 will be different from Excel 1 and these data will be displaying in Word 2 according to the new data in Excel 2.

-Word 2

-Excel 2

Answer (score 0):

No, I don't think it is possible as you put it. But something very similar should work.

`Word1` is internally storing reference to `Excel1` and this reference is not going to change if you rename `Word1` to `Word2`.

But you could create this directory structure and instead of copying and renaming the Word file, you would copy and rename whole folder:

- folder `Data1/`

  - file `Word.docx` (`Word.docx` points to `Excel.xlsx` in this folder)
  - file `Excel.xlsx`

and then copy the folder as `Data2`:

- folder `Data2/`

  - file `Word.docx` (`Word.docx` points to `Excel.xlsx` **in this folder**)
  - file `Excel.xlsx`

I assume the reference to the Excel file is *relative*, otherwise it won't work.